# Divergence rate of harmonic series on $\Bbb Z^d$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

We know that on $\Bbb Z$ we have that $\sum_{k = -N}^{N} \frac{1}{|k|}$ diverges at a rate of $\log(N)$.

I'm wondering if there is a similar identity for the rate of divergence of the series $$\sum_{k \in [-N,N]^d \cap \Bbb Z^d} \frac{1}{|k|^d}.$$

I'm not really sure how to even start with such a problem. We know that by the Euler-Maclaurin formulas, we can link the divergence of the above sum to the integral

$$ \int_{(0,\infty)} \! \rho^{-d} \rho^{d-1} \ \mathrm{d} \rho = \int_{(0,\infty)} \! \rho^{-1} \ \mathrm{d} \rho.$$

Where the last integral is "related" in some sense to the Harmonic series. My hope now is that the sum of $|k|^{-d}$ on $\Bbb Z^d$ is also divergent at a rate $\log(N)$, but I don't know how to make any of this rigorous. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: And I'm curious as to whether there is a general approach for studying the divergence of $|k|^{d-\alpha}$ as well, where $\alpha < d$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume $|k|$ is the Euclidean length of a vector. Call your sum be
$S_N$. Then $a_N=S_N-S_{N-1}$ is the sum of $1/|k|^d$ over all vectors
in $\Bbb Z^d$ with at least one entry $\pm N$. There are $(2N+1)^d-(2N-1)^d
=(2d+O(N^{-2}))(2N)^{d-1}$ such vectors, For such a vector $N\le|k|\le N\sqrt d$.
Therefore
$$C_1\frac{N^{d-1}}{N^d}\le a_N\le C_2\frac{N^{d-1}}{N^d}$$
where $0<C_1<C_2$. It follows that the divergence of $S_N$ is logarithmic,
just as in the $d=1$ case.

Comment: Makes sense! Thank you.